# Update User Info with Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');


const admin = require('firebase-admin');
//
var serviceAccount = require("-----");
//
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "---"
});


const uid = '--uid--'


admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
  email: '--new email--'
})
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log('Successfully updated user', userRecord.toJSON());
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error updating user:', error);
  });



exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    const email = user.email;
    const displayName = user.displayName;

    return sendWelcomeEmail(email, displayName);
});

// SEND WELCOME email
function sendWelcomeEmail(email, displayName) {
  const mailOptions = {
    from: '--- <noreply@firebase.com>',
    to: email
  };

  mailOptions.subject = '---';
  mailOptions.text = '---';

  return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions).then(() => {
    console.log('Welcome email sent to:', email);
  });
}
```

I had been using this to update users' email addresses for the past few years, but just today I tried again and the function is not running. I have other cloud functions in the same file that still runs, they have triggered events such as welcome Emails, but this function is no longer running. Any idea what might have changed? or why is it no longer working?

Comment: I don't see any usage of the `firebase-functions` SDK or event Cloud Functions in here, aside from the import. Can you edit your question to show how this code is support to be triggered?

Comment: So I'll be honest, it has been a few months since I used this, and I dont remember if there was an additional step to get this updateUser() to run. In this same file, further down, are a couple of cloud function triggers on user creation to send welcome emails and things of that sort. This might have been the wrong way to update a users email, but I used to just redeploy this file and a need to basis and it would trigger it that one time. I will edit question to include those function calls as well.

Comment: Did you try to functions.logger.log to debug yet? in your trigger, just do try catch and log, and from the firebase console -> functions -> logs to see what's wrong. Also check what is your current plan?  free or blaze.... sometime the problem with billing might occur